# Find a proper formula to calculate average with zero when cells are blank

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula to calculate sum of 3 cells one of them is a product of average of other three cells. the problem is when calculating the average of these cells while they are blank it gives error Div/0 and then the corresponding calculations are error too

maybe the solution is that if I want to calculate average of range of blank cells that the result to be zero but I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your formula with `=IFERROR(<Your formula>, 0)` to avoid getting unwanted errors with blank cells.

If you're using spanish version, you should use: `=SI.ERROR(<Your formula>; 0)`. Note the change between `,` and `;` between versions.

Thanks to @ForwardEd for noting my mistake!

Comment: You're right @ForwardEd!, I've made a mistake between spanish version function `=SI.ERROR(formula; <value if error>)` and english one `=IFERROR(formula, <value if error>)`. The `;` also changes for `,`in english Office. I'll edit the answer. Regards!